# Android - Losing focus on Item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, focus, listview-adapter

I have ListView with extendable items. Everything is working great until I trigger the dialog popup with EditText. Right after it animation just stop working. If I tap other button to animate the ListView container, everything coming back to normal.

In my ListViewAdapter I got item view in extends FrameLayout class and Animation is trigger when is called override onMeasure method with is not trigger after Soft Keyboard appear.

I think this is causing because there is no focus on particular item on the list?
Off course regular click on the list item is working fine.

Strange is also this on that when I hide soft keyboard by pressing back button everything also working as it should be.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show us some come so that we can try to reproduce the problem

Comment: What animation stops after you show the popup with the EditText?

Comment: I fixed everything, now is working great. Issue was my way how I was doing it. OnClickListener should be inside List Adapter, no in Activity.

Comment: A picture prints a thousand words please provide images..

Answer (score 3):

When you trigger the dialog popup with EditText, save the focus of the list view:

```
int focusedIndex = lstView.SelectedItems[0].Index;
```

You can then restore it by using:

```
lstView.Items[focusedIndex].Selected = true;
```

Comment: can you explain in more details

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs are modal, which means that they take away all the focus and get the user to only focus on their own UI. You need to not use a dialog, instead you need to use a `Fragment` or a `Activity` with `wrap_content` and a `RelativeLayout` to keep it small and in the center.